# Should I use ST or LT values for extruded rod?

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, stresses, strength, aluminum

In MMPDS for AA7075-73511 (extruded rod) the Table 3.7.10.0(g3) show both ST and LT values for transverse directions. For a rod with circular cross section there is really no Short and Long transverse directions. Which one should i choose? Do not want to be uneccassary conservative and choose ST-values if it is not applicable. In my case I'm looking at the higher end off the table with diameters around 4in.